# Representing a country using plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

So I want to represent my results on a bubble map using plotly. The problem is that I just found maps for the USA but I need for **Portugal**!

How can I set my map to represent Portugal?

Thank you in advance for your reply.

Comment: Did you check this [resource](https://community.plotly.com/t/choropleth-map-for-european-country/40803/8)?

Comment: @rpanai Fantastic tip! Would you consider writing up an example as an answer?

Comment: @Đorđe Klisura do you mind to share a sample of the data you want to plot?

Comment: Would you care to share your solution as an answer?

Comment: fig1.update_layout(
        lonaxis_range= [ -10.0, -6.0 ],
        lataxis_range= [ 36.0, 42.0 ],
        ) 
So on that way you limit the range to the county you want to present on a map :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transferring your comment to the answer box, as comments are temporary:

> ```
> fig1.update_layout( lonaxis_range= [ -10.0, -6.0 ], lataxis_range= [ 36.0, 42.0 ], )
> ```
>
> So on that way you limit the range to the county you want to present on a map :)